# Function returns undefined nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Here I'm creating an array that have property 1, then I'm trying to filter the results with only the highest number and then output it when calling the function, but it returns undefined. I'm trying to find to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks

```
function calcDifference() {
  table.find({
      "entries": 1
    }) // select entries with "entries":1
    .toArray(function(err, res_spr) { // create an array of found elements 
      let pop = res_spr.pop(); // delete last element of the array
      let storeArraySpr = []; // new array to store property "number"
      for (let i = 0; i < res_spr.length; i++) {
        storeArraySpr.push(res_spr[i].number);
      }

      var resultSpr = Math.max(...storeArraySpr); // select highest entry
      return resultSpr.toFixed(8); // meant to output the result when calling the function
    });
}

console.log(calcDifference()); // returns undefined
```

Comment: Change `table.find` to `return table.find`

Comment: @Barmar still returns undefined

Comment: What is `table`?

Comment: it's mongo database collection with objects:

Comment: `toArray()` is an asynchronous function. You need to use `await`.

Comment: When `toArray()` is called with a callback function, it doesn't return anything. See https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.5/classes/FindCursor.html#toArray

Comment: I appreciate you help, I'll dive in async function

Answer (score 1):

You haven't returned anything from that function.

You should add `return` before `table.find`

```
function calcDifference(){

      return table.find({"entries":1}) // select entries with "entries":1

        .toArray(function(err, res_spr) { // create an array of found elements 
 
              let pop = res_spr.pop(); // delete last element of the array

              let storeArraySpr = []; // new array to store property "number"

              for (let i = 0; i < res_spr.length; i++) { 

                storeArraySpr.push(res_spr[i].number); 

              }

              var resultSpr = Math.max(...storeArraySpr); // select highest entry

              return resultSpr.toFixed(8); // meant to output the result when calling the function
        });
    } 

    console.log(calcDifference());
```

---

If `toArray` does not return values in that callback function. You can assign a value and return it.

*Note that this approach will work if `toArray` and `find` do not return promises*

```
function calcDifference(){
      let result;
      table.find({"entries":1}) // select entries with "entries":1

        .toArray(function(err, res_spr) { // create an array of found elements 
 
              let pop = res_spr.pop(); // delete last element of the array

              let storeArraySpr = []; // new array to store property "number"

              for (let i = 0; i < res_spr.length; i++) { 

                storeArraySpr.push(res_spr[i].number); 

              }

              var resultSpr = Math.max(...storeArraySpr); // select highest entry

              result = resultSpr.toFixed(8); // meant to output the result when calling the function
        });

     return result; //return the final result from the callback function
    } 

    console.log(calcDifference());
```

---

The 3rd approach, if `find` and `toArray` are actually promises

```
async function calcDifference(){
      return await table.find({"entries":1}) // select entries with "entries":1

        .toArray(function(err, res_spr) { // create an array of found elements 
 
              let pop = res_spr.pop(); // delete last element of the array

              let storeArraySpr = []; // new array to store property "number"

              for (let i = 0; i < res_spr.length; i++) { 

                storeArraySpr.push(res_spr[i].number); 

              }

              var resultSpr = Math.max(...storeArraySpr); // select highest entry

              return resultSpr
        });
    } 

    console.log(await calcDifference());
```

---

If `toArray` does not return results, you can assign variable again, but the difference is now we have `async/await`

```
async function calcDifference(){
         let result;
         await table.find({"entries":1}) // select entries with "entries":1

        .toArray(function(err, res_spr) { // create an array of found elements 
 
              let pop = res_spr.pop(); // delete last element of the array

              let storeArraySpr = []; // new array to store property "number"

              for (let i = 0; i < res_spr.length; i++) { 

                storeArraySpr.push(res_spr[i].number); 

              }

              var resultSpr = Math.max(...storeArraySpr); // select highest entry

              result = resultSpr
        });
        return result
    } 

    console.log(await calcDifference());
```

Comment: still returns undefined.

Comment: what data `resultSpr` do you get? I'm suspecting that `resultSpr` has no data @D.M.

Comment: if gets highest value out of an array of elements with Double type.

Comment: could I know which library `toArray` is from? @D.M.

Comment: I use mongoose and express

Comment: When i log it (console.log(resultSpr.toFixed(8)) it logs the data with no problem, but it returns undefined when I call the function.

Comment: I put the 2nd approach in my answer. Hopefully, it's useful for your case @D.M.

Comment: Thank you for responses, it still doesn't do the trick. Someone said toArray() is an asynchronous function. ```await``` should be used instead.

Comment: Ohh I think it's worth trying different approaches. You can check the 3rd and 4th possible solutions for your case in my answer. It may give some hopes for potential fixes. @D.M.

Comment: ```console.log(await calcDifference()); ``` says SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: `await` needs to be in `async` function. You can execute it with `(async function() {
  console.log(await calcDifference());
})()` @D.M.

Comment: You also can try `then` instead. `calcDifference().then((result) => console.log(result))` @D.M.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that `calcDifference()` doesn't have a return value. To solve this you first need to change the way you call `toArray()`. Like Barman pointed out in the comments:

> When `toArray()` is called with a callback function, it doesn't return anything. See [mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.5/classes/…](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.5/classes/FindCursor.html#toArray) –
> [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72219436/function-returns-undefined-nodejs#comment127597048_72219436)

When you look at the documentation you'll find that it does return a promise if you do **not** pass a callback function. Firstly we change `calcDifference` to an `async function`. Then we `await table.find({ "entries": 1 }).toArray()` instead of passing a callback. After that you can do your other stuff.

Do note that an async function always returns a promise, so to use the return value you either have to `await` the value, or use a `then()` construct if you are not in async context.

```js
async function calcDifference() {
  const res_spr = await table.find({ "entries": 1 }).toArray(); // select entries with "entries":1
  
  let pop = res_spr.pop(); // delete last element of the array
  let storeArraySpr = []; // new array to store property "number"
  for (let i = 0; i < res_spr.length; i++) {
    storeArraySpr.push(res_spr[i].number);
  }

  var resultSpr = Math.max(...storeArraySpr); // select highest entry
  return resultSpr.toFixed(8); // meant to output the result when calling the function
}

// when in async context
console.log(await calcDifference());

// when not in async context
calcDifference().then(console.log);

// or if you need to execute multiple statements
calcDifference().then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
  // other stuff
});
```

Comment: Note that `storeArraySpr` can be simplified to `res_spr.slice(0, -1).map(item => item.number)`. This allows you to remove the `pop()` call and the for-loop.

Comment: ```console.log(await calcDifference());``` error on this line SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @D.M. Do you have `console.log(await calcDifference())` placed in an async function? If not, make sure that the function wrapping the statement is converted to an async function. If it already placed inside an async function, try splitting the statement in 2. `const result = await calcDifference()` and `console.log(result)`